# Android: change app widget's text on runtime before update time!

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

someone please tell me how can I update the TextView that is on app Widget, before default update period time is come.?.?.?.(30,om, or 1h... I set on 30mins but It updates on 1h)

So I have an activity which decides what is the final text on the widget, and it may be changed by user in the runtime, so after user changes something I should be able to show the final changes on widget (immediately),but I can't. how can I achieve this?

many thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I achieve this?

Just update the app widget via an `AppWidgetManager`. There is nothing magic about the "update time" -- you can update your app widget at any point. Construct your `RemoteViews`, configure them, and use the `AppWidgetManager` to push over the change to the home screen.

Comment: I can take advantage of AppWidgetManager inside Update method and actually I'm building remoteview there, could you please show some code lines how to use  "appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);" from inside other method?

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/34-AdvAppWidget/LunchList

Comment: how can i get "final int N = appWidgetIds.length;" ? how can I define appWidgetIds in my method?

Comment: @Varand pezeshk: That I can't answer, as I don't know your code. You only need to worry about that if you are support multiple app widgets each with unique content.